# Use Holder Inequality to show $ \sup \mathbb{E}(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>n})\to0$ if $ \sup_{n} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^{1+\delta}]<\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory

> For a sequence of r.v's $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, show that $ \sup_n E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>n})\to0$ as $n\to \infty$ if $ \sup_{n} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^{1+\delta}]<\infty, $ such that $\delta>0$.

I believe by dominated convergence that $ \sup E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>n})$ should converge to $0$.

We get $$\sup_{n} \mathbb{E}(|X_nX_n^{\delta}|) <\infty$$

I then tried to use Holder's inequality:

$$ \sup_nE[|X_nX_n^{\delta}|] \le \sup_nE(|X_n|)\sup_nE(|X_n^\delta|)^{1/\delta} $$

So really I want to show that $\sup_nE(|X_n|)$ and $\sup_nE(|X_n^\delta|)^{1/\delta} $ are finite, can we assume this? Not sure if I've answered this the right way... I'm not sure how this will imply $ \sup_n E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>n})\to0$?

Comment: What is $X$ in the first expectation? Should that be $X_n$?

Comment: @zugzug $X$ is a random variable, $(X_n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ are a sequence of these r.vs

Comment: But shouldn't there then be a relationship between $X_n$ and $X$? Otherwise, the information doesn't tell you anything about $X$.

Comment: Yeah so I **think** $E(|X|1_{|X|>n})$ is bounded by $E(|XnXn^{\delta}|)$, so If $Xn$ is bounded then so is $X$ but I'm not so sure..

Comment: I'm not sure you see my question. You have an $X$ and $X_n$ with no information connecting the two. It's like saying assume $z<5$. Prove $t<1$. I encourage you to double check how the question is written and if there are any assumptions about $X_n$ as it pertains to $X$.

Comment: My guess is $X$ is a given random variable and $X_n = X 1_{|X|>n}$, but I'm not sure

Comment: @zugzug Sorry, you're completely right! I've updated..

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be a lim sup? How can a sup over all $n$ converge? It's a single number.

Comment: It is essentially a limit. The supremum converges as $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a hint. Applying Holder's, we need $p>1$ and $q>1$ such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Choose $p=1+\delta>1$. Then $q=\frac{p}{p-1}=\frac{1+\delta}{\delta}$.

Hence,
$$
\int_\Omega |X_n|\,\cdot 1_{|X_n|>n}\, d\omega\leq \left(\int_\Omega |X_n|^p\, d\omega\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_\Omega 1^q_{|X_n|>n}\, d\omega\right)^{1/q}
$$
holds for all $n$. If you take supremums of both sides, consider the two terms on the right. The first one is bounded by hypotheses. Then for the second term, the integral of a characteristic function is just the probability measure. These hints should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1_{|X_n|>n} \le \frac{|X_n|^\delta}{n^\delta}$, so

$$ E[|X_n|1_{|X_n|>n}] \le \frac1{n^{\delta}}E[|X_n|^{1+\delta}] \le \frac{C}{n^{\delta}}, $$

where $C:=\sup_n E[|X_n|^{1+\delta}] < \infty$. Now take limits.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't specifically use Holder's Inequality.

Comment: Holder's inequality is not at all necessary, but one could easily apply it instead of the first inequality with $p=1+\delta$. You will find $E[|X_n|1_{|X_n|>n}] \le (E[|X_n|^{1+\delta}])^{1/(1+\delta)}\cdot P(|X_n|>n)^{1/q}$ where $q>1$ is the dual exponent of $1+\delta$. The first term is bounded by $C^{1/(1+\delta)}$, and you can apply Markov's inequality to the probability (or once again use $1_{|X_n|>n} \le |X_n|/n$).